# Cómo configurar PhpSpreadsheet con formato de texto en celdas conteniendo números?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

tengo un problema o duda o consulta.
Consiste en cuando yo genero un excel con la librería de PHP PhpSpreadsheet, y le doy un valor a una celda por ejemplo a la celda A3 y le configuro el formato de numero que sea TEXTO pero a esa celda le asigno un numero por ejemplo 23432523253234 pero quiero que el formato sea TEXTO.
Codigo que utilizo

```
require 'controllers/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
$documento = new Spreadsheet();
    $documento->getProperties()
        ->setCreator("Yo")
        ->setLastModifiedBy('System')
        ->setTitle('Excel ')
        ->setSubject('Reporte')
        ->setDescription('Este documento fue generado por Yo');
$hoja = $documento->getActiveSheet();
 $hoja->setCellValue("A1", "Celda de prueba");
$hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(14);
$hoja->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('4791F5');
    $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');
```

Aqui donde le asigno el valor

```
$hoja->setCellValue("A2", "477734312711146");


$hoja->getColumnDimension("A")->setAutoSize(true);
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($documento, 'Xlsx');
$filename = 'Reporte.xlsx';
$file_location = 'uploads/' . $filename;
$writer->save($filename);'
```

Ahora el problema o el inconveniente que tengo es que al momento de abrir el excel el numero que coloque 477734312711146 me sale así:
[image: Imagen de referencia]

Si observan en la imagen en la celda en si, se mira el numero acortado 4.77734E+14 y en el cuadro de en medio para visualizar la información me sale el numero correcto y si pueden ver el formato de numero esta en TEXTO.

Pregunta como puedo configurar que PhpSpreadsheet no me haga el numero acortado?.

Comment: Una solución rápida (no sé si la mejor) es concatenar al inicio de dicho "número" el carácter `'`. Saludos.

Comment: El problema ha sido abordado en Github ([ver discusión aquí](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/357)). En muchos casos la solución ha sido aplicar `setFormatCode('#');` aparte de indicar `setDataType(DataType::TYPE_STRING);`.

Answer (score 0):

Por ahí [vi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31162557/236345) que podría funcionar con el quotePrefix como te indicaron en el comentario.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A2:O128')
    ->setQuotePrefix(true);
```

Otros [indican](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39073394/236345) que les funciona dando formato de texto:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('A'.$i)
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(
    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

$sheet->getStyle("J2")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);

Esta solución es fantástica

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con este código para poner la celda en formato número normal:

`$sheet->getStyle("J2")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);`

$sheet se corresponde con la hoja activa y "J2" la celda que quieras dar ese formato. Con esto se consigue que la celda muestre el número completo sin acortarlo automáticamente.

Comment: El amigo quiere formato Texto, no número

Comment: El amigo pide, cito TEXTUALMENTE "Pregunta como puedo configurar que PhpSpreadsheet no me haga el numero acortado?."
Esto solucionar su problema :)